# How to output the name of node which I use by using pbs script

Tags: shell, pbs

I need to output in the file the name of node on which my job is running, by using .pbs script. I need only the name of node, so I'm not interested in

> qstat -n -u username

command. Could You help me?

Comment: Are you doing this inside the job? The command hostname should take care of you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the environment variables. Add this entry in your .pbs:

echo $PBS_O_HOST

more on http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/4-0-2/Content/topics/commands/qsub.htm